# Why does Nativescript page break on iOS device?

Tags: ios, xml, nativescript

[image: picture]

Hello,
Whenever I try to insert some data on my NS app, page breaks for few seconds. Sometimes it happens for less than a second. This problem occurs only when the checklist is long. And most of the cases I have long checklist. I am using the NS version 6 and this was working well on version 5. Does anybody know the reason? Thanks

JS Method : 
             ```function setComponents( newComponents ) {
    while (currentComponents.length) {
        currentComponents.pop();
    }
    //pageData.set("isLoading", true);
    //setTimeout( function () {
    if ( currentComponents.length < 1 ) {

```
    newComponents.forEach( function ( newComponent ) {
        var userInputComponent = "";
        if ( typeof newComponent.userInput !== "undefined" ) {
            userInputComponent = newComponent.userInput;
        }

        var mNotice = "";
        if ( typeof newComponent.mNotice !== "undefined" ) {
            mNotice = newComponent.mNotice;
        }

        var comment = newComponent.comment;
        if ( comment && comment.trim() !== "" ) {
            commentVisibility = "visible";
        }
        else {
            commentVisibility = "collapsed";
        }

        var options;
        var mNoticeVisible = "collapsed";
        var mUnit = "";
        var imgCollapse = "collapsed";
        var maxLenTextTypeField = "400";
        var dateVisibility = "collapsed";
        var timeVisibility = "collapsed";
        var timeHint = "";
        var imgList = ["", "", "", ""];
        var imgCollapseList = ["collapsed", "collapsed", "collapsed", "collapsed"];

        switch ( newComponent.cType ) {
            case "yesnoType":
                options = getMultipleChoiceYesNoTypeOptions ( newComponent.id, newComponent.cOptions );
                options.forEach( function ( opt ) {
                    if ( userInputComponent !== "" && opt.optText === userInputComponent ) {
                        opt.check = "\uf046";
                    } else {
                        opt.check = "\uf096";
                    }
                });

                var isNoticeVisible = isSetMultipleChoiceYesNoTypeNotice( newComponent.cOptions );

                if ( isNoticeVisible ) {
                    mNoticeVisible = "visible";
                }

                break;

            case "textType":
                options = "";
                var isNoticeVisible = isSetTextTypeNotice( newComponent.cOptions );
                var isOneLine = isTextTypeOneLine( newComponent.cOptions  );

                if ( isNoticeVisible ) {
                    mNoticeVisible = "visible";
                }

                if ( isOneLine ) {
                    maxLenTextTypeField = "40";
                }
                break;
            case "freetextType":
                options = "";
                break;

            case "multiplechoiceType":
                options = getMultipleChoiceYesNoTypeOptions ( newComponent.id, newComponent.cOptions );
                options.forEach( function ( opt ) {
                    opt.check = "\uf096";
                    if ( userInputComponent !== "" ) {

                        var uicArr = userInputComponent.split("##|#<");
                        for ( var i = 0; i < uicArr.length; i++ ) {

                            if ( opt.optText === uicArr[i] ) {
                                opt.check = "\uf046";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                var isNoticeVisible = isSetMultipleChoiceYesNoTypeNotice( newComponent.cOptions );

                if ( isNoticeVisible ) {
                    mNoticeVisible = "visible";
                }

                break;

            case "photoType":
                if ( userInputComponent !== "" ) { 
                    imgCollapse = "visible";
                    var listImg = userInputComponent.split("~###~");
                    if (listImg.length > 0 && listImg[0]) {
                        for ( var i = 0; i < listImg.length; i++ ) {
                            imgList[i] = listImg[i];
                            imgCollapse[i] = "visible";
                        }

                    }
                }

                options = "";
                var isNoticeVisible = isSetTypeNotice( newComponent.cOptions );

                if ( isNoticeVisible ) {
                    mNoticeVisible = "visible";
                }

                break;

            case "signatureType":
                if ( userInputComponent !== "" ) { 
                    imgCollapse = "visible";
                }

                options = newComponent.cOptions;

                var isNoticeVisible = isSetTypeNotice( newComponent.cOptions );

                if ( isNoticeVisible ) {
                    mNoticeVisible = "visible";
                }

                break;

            case "measuringdataType":
                var isNoticeVisible = isSetMeasuringDataTypeNotice( newComponent.cOptions );

                if ( isNoticeVisible ) {
                    mNoticeVisible = "visible";
                }

                options = getMeasuringDataTypeOptions ( newComponent.cOptions );

                if ( userInputComponent !== "" ) {
                    var uicArr = userInputComponent.split("##|#<");

                    for ( var i = 0; i < options.length; i++ ) {
                        options.getItem(i).userInput = uicArr[i].substring(1);
                    }
                }

                break;

            case "timeType":

                if ( isDateVisibile( newComponent.cOptions ) ) {
                    dateVisibility = "visible";

                    if ( isTimeVisibile( newComponent.cOptions ) ) {
                        timeHint = "dd.MM.YYYY HH:mm";
                    }
                    else {
                        timeHint = "dd.MM.YYYY";
                    }
                }

                if ( isTimeVisibile( newComponent.cOptions ) ) {
                    timeVisibility = "visible";

                    if ( timeHint === "" ) {
                        timeHint = "HH:mm";
                    }
                }

                var isNoticeVisible = isSetTextTypeNotice( newComponent.cOptions );

                if ( isNoticeVisible ) {
                    mNoticeVisible = "visible";
                }

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }


        var ipXClass = "";
        if (app.ios) {
            if (height == 1125 && width == 2436) {
                ipXClass = "ipXClass";
            }
        }

        currentComponents.push({
            id: newComponent.id,
            sortIndex: newComponent.sortIndex,
            sectionId: newComponent.sectionId,
            componentName: newComponent.componentName,
            cType: newComponent.cType,
            cOptions: options,
            mNoticeVisible: mNoticeVisible,
            maxLenTextTxpe: maxLenTextTypeField,
            mNotice: mNotice,
            mUnit: mUnit,
            imgCollapse: imgCollapse,
            comment: newComponent.comment,
            commentVisibility: commentVisibility,
            dateVisibility: dateVisibility,
            timeVisibility: timeVisibility,
            timeHint: timeHint,
            //datePickerID: "d-" + newComponent.id,
            //timePickerID: "t-" + newComponent.id,
            userInput: userInputComponent,
            listId: "list-" + newComponent.id,
            imgID: "img" + newComponent.id,
            imgID_0: "img" + newComponent.id + "_0",
            imgID_1: "img" + newComponent.id + "_1",
            imgID_2: "img" + newComponent.id + "_2",
            imgID_3: "img" + newComponent.id + "_3",
            img_0: imgList[0],
            img_1: imgList[1],
            img_2: imgList[2],
            img_3: imgList[3],
            imgCollapse_0: imgCollapseList[0],
            imgCollapse_1: imgCollapseList[1],
            imgCollapse_2: imgCollapseList[2],
            imgCollapse_3: imgCollapseList[3],
            ipXClass: ipXClass
        });

    });

}
```

}```
XML file:

````
            <GridLayout rows="auto,*, auto">
                <StackLayout row="0" class="pageTitle title">
                    <Label text="{{ checklistName }}" textWrap="true" class="titleBig"/>
                    <Label text="{{ sectionName }}" textWrap="true" class="titleSmall" />
                </StackLayout>
                <ActivityIndicator busy="{{ isLoading }}" rowSpan="2" colSpan="2" width="90"/>
                <StackLayout row="1">
                    <lv:RadListView items="{{ components }}" itemTemplateSelector="selectTemplate" id="cList" margin="10">
                        <lv:RadListView.itemTemplates>
                            <template key="yesnoType">
                                <StackLayout class="componentContent">
                                    <GridLayout columns="*, 50" class="{{ ipXClass }}">
                                        <Label col="0" textWrap="true" text="{{ componentName }}" class="cTitle"/>
                                        <StackLayout col="1" visibility="{{ commentVisibility }}" width="50">
                                            <Label text="&#xf05a;" tap="openInfoCL" data="{{ comment }}" class="font-awesome h2 title InfoBtn" horizontalAlignment="left" verticalAlignment="top"/>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </GridLayout>
                                    <Label visibility="collapsed" id="{{ id }}" text="{{ userInput }}"/>
                                    <Repeater items="{{ cOptions }}" id="{{ listId }}" class="m-l-20">
                                        <Repeater.itemsLayout>
                                            <StackLayout />
                                        </Repeater.itemsLayout>
                                        <Repeater.itemTemplate>
                                            <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" class="m-l-15 cInput" data="{{ optId }}" datatext="{{ optText }}" tap="toggleSelectYesNo">
                                                <Label id="{{ optId }}" text="{{ check }}" class="font-awesome checkbox" data="{{ optText }}" textWrap="true" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center"/>
                                                <Label text="{{ optText }}" textWrap="true" horizontalAlignment="left" verticalAlignment="center"/>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </Repeater.itemTemplate>
                                    </Repeater>
                                    <TextField loaded="textFieldLoaded" class="m-l-15 m-t-10" hint="Bemerkung hinzufügen" text="{{ mNotice }}" visibility="{{ mNoticeVisible }}" returnKeyType="next" maxLength="250"/>
                                    <Border class="list-border" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </template>
                            <template key="textType">
                                <StackLayout class="componentContent" class="{{ ipXClass }}">
                                    <GridLayout columns="*, 50">
                                        <Label col="0" textWrap="true" text="{{ componentName }}" class="cTitle"/>
                                        <StackLayout col="1" visibility="{{ commentVisibility }}" width="50">
                                            <Label text="&#xf05a;" tap="openInfoCL" data="{{ comment }}" class="font-awesome h2 title InfoBtn" horizontalAlignment="left" verticalAlignment="top"/>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </GridLayout>
                                    <StackLayout class="m-l-20">
                                        <TextField loaded="textFieldLoaded" hint="Ihr Text" text="{{ userInput }}" returnKeyType="next" maxLength="{{ maxLenTextTxpe }}" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                    <TextField loaded="textFieldLoaded" class="m-l-15  m-t-10" hint="Bemerkung hinzufügen" text="{{ mNotice }}" visibility="{{ mNoticeVisible }}" returnKeyType="next" maxLength="250"/>
                                    <Border class="list-border" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </template>
                            <template key="freetextType">
                                <StackLayout class="componentContent" class="{{ ipXClass }}">
                                    <Label textWrap="true" text="{{ componentName }}" class="cTitle"/>
                                    <Border class="list-border" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </template>
                            <template key="multiplechoiceType">
                                <StackLayout class="componentContent" class="{{ ipXClass }}">
                                    <GridLayout columns="*, 50">
                                        <Label col="0" textWrap="true" text="{{ componentName }}" class="cTitle"/>
                                        <StackLayout col="1" visibility="{{ commentVisibility }}" width="50">
                                            <Label text="&#xf05a;" tap="openInfoCL" data="{{ comment }}" class="font-awesome h2 title InfoBtn" horizontalAlignment="left" verticalAlignment="top"/>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </GridLayout>
                                    <Label visibility="collapsed" id="{{ id }}" text="{{ userInput }}"/>
                                    <Repeater items="{{ cOptions }}" id="{{ listId }}" class="m-l-20">
                                        <Repeater.itemsLayout>
                                            <StackLayout />
                                        </Repeater.itemsLayout>
                                        <Repeater.itemTemplate>
                                            <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" class="m-l-15 cInput" data="{{ optId }}" datatext="{{ optText }}" tap="selectMultiple">
                                                <Label id="{{ optId }}" text="{{ check }}" class="font-awesome checkbox" textWrap="true" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center"/>
                                                <Label text="{{ optText }}" textWrap="true" horizontalAlignment="left" verticalAlignment="center"/>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </Repeater.itemTemplate>
                                    </Repeater>
                                    <TextField loaded="textFieldLoaded" class="m-l-15 m-t-10" hint="Bemerkung hinzufügen" text="{{ mNotice }}" visibility="{{ mNoticeVisible }}" returnKeyType="next" maxLength="250"/>
                                    <Border class="list-border" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </template>
                            <template key="photoType">
                                <StackLayout class="componentContent" class="{{ ipXClass }}" >
                                    <GridLayout columns="*, 50" >
                                        <Label col="0" textWrap="true" text="{{ componentName }}" class="cTitle"/>
                                        <StackLayout col="1" visibility="{{ commentVisibility }}" width="50">
                                            <Label text="&#xf05a;" tap="openInfoCL" data="{{ comment }}" class="font-awesome h2 title InfoBtn" horizontalAlignment="left" verticalAlignment="top"/>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </GridLayout>
                                    <Image id="{{ imgID_0 }}" src="{{ img_0 }}" visibility="{{ imgCollapse_0 }}" class="image" stretch="aspectFit" horizontalAlignment="left" />
                                    <Image id="{{ imgID_1 }}" src="{{ img_1 }}" visibility="{{ imgCollapse_1 }}" class="image" stretch="aspectFit" horizontalAlignment="left" />
                                    <Image id="{{ imgID_2 }}" src="{{ img_2 }}" visibility="{{ imgCollapse_2 }}" class="image" stretch="aspectFit" horizontalAlignment="left" />
                                    <Image id="{{ imgID_3 }}" src="{{ img_3 }}" visibility="{{ imgCollapse_3 }}" class="image" stretch="aspectFit" horizontalAlignment="left" />
                                    <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" class="m-l-20">
                                        <!--<Button text="&#xf030;" class="font-awesome imageBtnSmall" data="{{ id }}" sortIndex="{{ sortIndex }}" tap="capturePhoto"/>-->
                                        <Button text="&#xf03e;" class="font-awesome imageBtnSmall" data="{{ id }}" sortIndex="{{ sortIndex }}" tap="getPhotoFromGallery"/>
                                        <Button text="&#xf00d;" class="font-awesome imageBtnSmall" data="{{ id }}" sortIndex="{{ sortIndex }}" tap="removePhoto"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                    <TextField loaded="textFieldLoaded" class="m-l-15 m-t-10" hint="Bemerkung hinzufügen" text="{{ mNotice }}" visibility="{{ mNoticeVisible }}" returnKeyType="next" maxLength="250"/>
                                    <Border class="list-border" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </template>
                            <template key="measuringdataType">
                                <StackLayout class="componentContent">
                                    <GridLayout columns="*, 50" class="{{ ipXClass }}">
                                        <Label col="0" textWrap="true" text="{{ componentName }}" class="cTitle"/>
                                        <StackLayout col="1" visibility="{{ commentVisibility }}" width="50">
                                            <Label text="&#xf05a;" tap="openInfoCL" data="{{ comment }}" class="font-awesome h2 title InfoBtn" horizontalAlignment="left" verticalAlignment="top"/>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </GridLayout>
                                    <Label visibility="collapsed" id="{{ id }}" text="{{ userInput }}"/>
                                    <Repeater items="{{ cOptions }}" id="{{ listId }}" class="m-l-20">
                                        <Repeater.itemsLayout>
                                            <StackLayout />
                                        </Repeater.itemsLayout>
                                        <Repeater.itemTemplate>
                                            <StackLayout class="m-l-15 cInput">
                                                <StackLayout>
                                                    <Label text="{{ optText }}" textWrap="true"/>
                                                </StackLayout>
                                                <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
                                                    <android>
                                                        <TextField loaded="textFieldLoaded" hint="z.B. 0,1" text="{{ userInput }}" class="measuringVal" tap="androidFixCommaTextFieldNumber" keyboardType="number" returnKeyType="next" maxLength="15"/>
                                                    </android>
                                                    <ios>
                                                        <TextField loaded="textFieldLoaded" hint="z.B. 0,1" text="{{ userInput }}" class="measuringVal" keyboardType="number" returnKeyType="next" maxLength="15"/>
                                                    </ios>
                                                    <Label text="{{ mUnit }}" class="mUnit"/>
                                                </StackLayout>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </Repeater.itemTemplate>
                                    </Repeater>
                                    <android>
                                        <TextField loaded="textFieldLoaded" class="m-l-15 m-t-10" hint="Bemerkung hinzufügen" editable="false" tap="androidTextFieldFocus" text="{{ mNotice }}" visibility="{{ mNoticeVisible }}" returnKeyType="next" maxLength="250"/>
                                    </android>
                                    <ios>
                                        <TextField loaded="textFieldLoaded" class="m-l-15 m-t-10" hint="Bemerkung hinzufügen" text="{{ mNotice }}" visibility="{{ mNoticeVisible }}" returnKeyType="next" maxLength="250"/>
                                    </ios>
                                    <Border class="list-border" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </template>
                            <template key="timeType">
                                <StackLayout class="componentContent" class="{{ ipXClass }}" >
                                    <GridLayout columns="*, 50">
                                        <Label col="0" textWrap="true" text="{{ componentName }}" class="cTitle"/>
                                        <Label col="1" text="&#xf05a;" class="font-awesome h2 title InfoBtn" tap="openInfoCL" data="{{ comment }}" visibility="{{ commentVisibility }}" horizontalAlignment="right" verticalAlignment="top" padding="10"/>
                                    </GridLayout>
                                    <StackLayout class="m-l-20">
                                        <TextView id="{{ id }}" loaded="textFieldLoaded" hint="{{ timeHint }}" text="{{ userInput }}" editable="false" isEnabled="false" returnKeyType="next" maxLength="100"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                    <!--
                                    <DatePicker class="m-l-20" id="{{ datePickerID }}" verticalAlignment="center" horizontalAlignment="left" visibility="{{ dateVisibility }}" style="margin-bottom: -15; margin-top: -15"/>
                                    <TimePicker class="m-l-20" id="{{ timePickerID }}" verticalAlignment="center" horizontalAlignment="left" visibility="{{ timeVisibility }}" style="margin-bottom: -15; margin-top: -15"/>
                                    -->
                                    <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" class="m-l-20">
                                    <!--
                                        <Button text="&#xf073;" class="font-awesome imageBtnSmall" data="{{ id }}" sortIndex="{{ sortIndex }}" visibility="{{ dateVisibility }}" tap="setDate"/>
                                        <Button text="&#xf017;" class="font-awesome imageBtnSmall" data="{{ id }}" sortIndex="{{ sortIndex }}" visibility="{{ timeVisibility }}" tap="setTime"/>
                                        -->
                                        <Button text="&#xf073; &#xf017;" class="font-awesome imageBtnSmall" data="{{ id }}" sortIndex="{{ sortIndex }}" tap="captureTime"/>
                                        <Button text="&#xf00d;" class="font-awesome imageBtnSmall" data="{{ id }}" sortIndex="{{ sortIndex }}" tap="clearTime"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                    <TextField loaded="textFieldLoaded" class="m-l-15 m-t-10" hint="Bemerkung hinzufügen" text="{{ mNotice }}" visibility="{{ mNoticeVisible }}" returnKeyType="next" maxLength="250"/>
                                    <Border class="list-border" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </template>
                            <template key="signatureType">
                                <StackLayout class="componentContent" class="{{ ipXClass }}" >
                                    <GridLayout columns="*, 50">
                                        <Label col="0" textWrap="true" text="{{ componentName }}" class="cTitle"/>
                                        <Label col="1" text="&#xf05a;" class="font-awesome h2 title InfoBtn" tap="openInfoCL" data="{{ comment }}" visibility="{{ commentVisibility }}" horizontalAlignment="right" verticalAlignment="top" padding="10"/>
                                    </GridLayout>
                                    <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" class="m-l-20">
                                        <Button text="&#xf14b;" class="font-awesome imageBtnSmall" data="{{ id }}" sortIndex="{{ sortIndex }}" tap="captureSignature"/>
                                        <Button text="&#xf03e;" class="font-awesome imageBtnSmall" data="{{ id }}" sortIndex="{{ sortIndex }}" tap="getPhotoFromGallery"/>
                                        <Button text="&#xf00d;" class="font-awesome imageBtnSmall" data="{{ id }}" sortIndex="{{ sortIndex }}" tap="clearSignature"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                    <Image id="{{ imgID }}" src="{{ userInput }}" visibility="{{ imgCollapse }}" class="image" stretch="aspectFit" horizontalAlignment="left"/>
                                    <TextField loaded="textFieldLoaded" class="m-l-15 m-t-10" hint="Bemerkung hinzufügen" text="{{ mNotice }}" visibility="{{ mNoticeVisible }}" returnKeyType="next" maxLength="250"/>
                                    <Border class="list-border" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </template>
                        </lv:RadListView.itemTemplates>
                    </lv:RadListView>
                </StackLayout>
                <GridLayout id="bottomButtons" row="2" columns="100,*,100" ios:height="60" visibility="hidden">
                    <Button col="0" text="&#xf0a8;  Zurück" tap="gotoPrevSection" android:class="ooe-btn-android font-awesome" ios:class="twoBottomBtns ooe-btn-ios font-awesome"/>
                    <Button col="1" text="&#xf0c7;  Speichern" tap="saveCL" android:class="ooe-btn-android font-awesome" ios:class="twoBottomBtns ooe-btn-ios font-awesome"/>
                    <Button col="2" android:text="&#xf0a9;  Weiter" ios:text="Weiter  &#xf0a9;" tap="gotoNextSection" android:class="ooe-btn-android font-awesome" ios:class="twoBottomBtns ooe-btn-ios font-awesome"/>
                </GridLayout>
            </GridLayout>
        </sd:RadSideDrawer.mainContent>```
````

Comment: Can you share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: @Manoj .. I tried but could not make a playground sample :(

Comment: @Manoj have added the JS method in my post, if it helps to get an idea?

Comment: You are not suppose to use Repeaters in list view, the whole idea of list view is making template static and reusing the views. You may consider using nested list view plugin to render list within a list.

Comment: @Manoj Could you please refer an example if possible?